# JavaScript - Apply one method to many objects

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, undefined

I have heard about the prototype method to apply one function or variable to several objects. But it does not work for me somehow. I created many objects kind of like this:

```
var item = {
  a: {
    aa: "lalala",
    ab: 1,
    something: 3
  },
  b: {
    ba: "jfjb",
    bb: 2,
    something: 4
  }
}
```

But when I know use the prototype method

```
item.prototype.bob = 2;
```

it does not work and shows me the error

> Cannot set property 'bob' of undefined"

Same for a method

```
item.prototype.bob = function() {
   100 - this.something;
   this.something++;
}
```

Do you know what I do wrong or is there a different method to apply the same variable or function to many objects?

Comment: The problem is not the type that you assign, but the type of `item`. So `item.prototype` is `undefined`. And you can't call `.bob` on `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You confuse classes with object instances. You just have an anonymous object. `item` is the instance, not the class.

In the snippet below, a class is declared (`Item`, with capital i), an instance is created (`item`), and the prototype *of the class* is modified. You will see then that you can set a property on the prototype and read it though the instance, if you like.

```js
var Item = function() {
  a = {
    aa: "lalala",
    ab: 1,
    something: 3
  };
  b = {
    ba: "jfjb",
    bb: 2,
    something: 4
  };
}

var item = new Item();

Item.prototype.bob = 'x';

alert(item.bob);
```

Answer (score 1):

The classic way is

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log(this.firstName + " says hello");
}

var pete = new Person("Peter", "Pan");

pete.greet();
```

Note that the prototype attribute is on the constructor (the function object we invoke with `new` to construct the object), not the constructed object itself.

In ECMAScript 6, you'll be able to write this in a more compact way:

```
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    greet() {
        console.log(this.firstName + " says hello");
    }
}

new Person("Peter", "Pan").greet();
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototype property is called on the class name and not on the object name. So, if item is an object of class MyClass then you should write:

```
MyClass.prototype.bob = 2;
```

You can find more information on the links below:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_prototype5
- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here your item is an object by itself,it does not has any constructor, so you cannot define or set on prototype.Your code throws error

To fix this, it has to be something like the below

```
function item(a,b){
   this.a=a;
   this.b=b;
}
function a(aa,ab,something){
   this.aa=aa;
   this.ab=ab;
   this.something=something
}
item.prototype.bob=2;
item.prototype.method1 = function() {
   100 - this.something;
   this.something++;
}
```

Hope this helps